# How can I add an interceptor in Spring Boot application which is activated after annotation validation and before controller call?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, interceptor

In my Spring Boot app I have a controller, which has and endpoint which receives a request object.

This object has @Valid annotation on it (inside the object there are some @NotNull annotation on some fields).

I want to register an interceptor, which:

1. first waits for annotation validation to be executed on the request object
2. if there were no validation error then the interceptor content is executed
3. after interceptor, the code of endpont method in the controller is executed

How can I do this with interceptor? Or should I use some other solutions?